# Trocar código de elseif para switch case

Tags: php, if, switch, else, case

Estou tendo problemas em alterar um código que fiz em `else if` para `switch` `case`. Não estou a conseguir que o código funcione, ele recebe valores e operação pelo `$_GET` e faz a operação selecionada:

Deixo o código aqui:

```
if((!is_numeric($num1) || $num1 == '' || $num1 == '0') && $operator == '/') 
    echo "ERRO: Numero 1 inserido e' zero";
else if((!is_numeric($num2) || $num2 == '' || $num2 == '0') && $operator == '/') 
    echo "ERRO: Numero 2 inserido e' zero";
else {
   //se a divisao for feita por zero, da mensagem de erro informando que o valor inserido foi zero
    if( !empty($operator) ) {
        if($operator == '+')
            $result = $num1 + $num2;
        else if($operator == '-')
            $result = $num1 - $num2;
        else if($operator == '*')
            $result = $num1*$num2;
        else
            $result = $num1/$num2;
        echo "O resultado é: ".$result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Mostre o que fez com `switch`. E diga qual é o problema que encontrou.

Comment: não fiz muito ainda, nao sei como passar para switch case a primeira parte do !is_numeric

Comment: vc precisa 'separar' a validação dos números de entrada com a escolha da operação, o switch provavelmente será aplicado somente na escolha da operação.

Comment: Vou tentar responder o que dá mas só com este trecho de código não poderei ajudar muita coisa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisaria melhorar muita coisa, mas basicamente seria isto:

```
if (!is_numeric($num1) || !is_numeric($num2) {
    echo "ERRO: as entradas precisam ser numéricas";
    //encerra de alguma forma, dpende do código.
}
$num1 = intval($num1); //pode  ser um floatval
$num2 = intval($num2);
switch ($operator) {
    case '+':
        $result = $num1 + $num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        $result = $num1 - $num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        $result = $num1 * $num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        if ($num2 == 0) {
            echo "ERRO: Não pode fazer divisão por zero";
            break;
        }
        $result = $num1 / $num2;
        break;
    default:
        //talvez mereça alguma mensagem de erro se não for nenhum operador válido
}
echo "O resultado é: " . $result;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Calculate.php).

Não converta para o `switch` o que o `if` funciona melhor, faça isso apenas com a escolha dos operadores.

Não esqueça de converter os valores que estão como texto para numérico para fazer a conta apropriadamente.

O teste se é numérico é um pouco ingênuo.

O teste se o valor do divisor é 0 só precisa ser feito se o operador for de divisão, então coloca isso lá. E o dividendo pode ser 0.

Tem várias outras coisas que poderiam ser feitas de forma melhor.

Talvez a dificuldade seja porque não estava separando cada responsabilidade. Uma coisa é verificar se os dados estão dentro dos padrões mínimos para fazer algo útil, outra coisa e selecionar o que fazer. Não acho que compense verificar o valor condicional separadamente (caso da divisão por 0).

Precisa ver se quer só inteiros ou também valores decimais. Tem uma série de outras decisões para fazer um código bom para uso. Se era um exercício básico então teria sido melhor pelo menos tentar fazer o que deseja.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Ainda sou novato no php! abraço

Comment: +1, especialmente pelo aviso "Não converta para o switch o que o if funciona melhor, faça isto apenas com a escolha dos operadores."

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar assim:

```
    $num1 = $_GET['num1']; 
    $operator = $_GET['operator']; 
    $num2 = $_GET['num2']; 

    switch (true) {
    case !is_numeric($num1) && $operator == '/':
    case $num1 == '' && $operator == '/':
    case $num1 == '0' && $operator == '/':
        echo "ERRO: Numero 1 inserido e' zero";
        break;

    case !is_numeric($num2) && $operator == '/':
    case $num2 == '' && $operator == '/':
    case $num2 == '0' && $operator == '/':
        echo "ERRO: Numero 2 inserido e' zero";
        break;
    default:
        switch ($operator) {
            case '+':
                $result = $num1 + $num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                $result = $num1 - $num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                $result = $num1 * $num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                $result = $num1 / $num2;
                break;
        }
        echo "O resultado é: ".$result;
    }
```

Comment: Olá Ricardo, vou tentar, mas parece-me a forma mais correcta! obrigado :)

Comment: Eu testei e funcionou aqui Mario. Caso não consiga poste o código pra nós.

Comment: Ricardo, funcionou em beleza! Muito obrigado! Estou aprendendo ainda php, desculpe se o codigo antes tinha falhas de iniciante! Abraço

Comment: `switch true` foi a primeira vez que eu vi :)

Comment: @bigown o pior vai ser quando ele for tentar usar switch invertido numa linguagem mais séria e perceber que só funciona em PHP pq nao é  otimizado .

Comment: @RicardoMota não precisa colocar "Espero ter ajudado" em todas suas respostas. A comunidade reconhece isso pelas respostas que você tem dado. Acompanha a [discussão no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5458/o-que-fazer-com-o-espero-ter-ajudado-no-final-das-respostas)