# É correto usar um switch dentro de um for?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, for, otimização, switch

Me veio uma dúvida relacionado a utilização de um switch dentro de um `for`. Eu vi que funciona para o meu propósito mas isso é correto de se fazer no mundo da programação?

Existe uma forma melhor de obter o resultado sem a utilização de um `switch` dentro do `for`, a partir do código abaixo?

```
    for (var index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {
    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            console.log(`Repeating because one is less than ten !`)
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log(`Repeating because two is less than ten !`)
            break;
        case 3:
        console.log(`Repeating because three is less than ten !`)
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Repeating because ${index} is less than ten !`)
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correto nem sempre é fácil de dizer, estritamente falando é correto porque funciona e dá o resultado que deseja em todas situações desse trecho, então ninguém pode dizer que está errado. Não é a forma mais eficiente, mais curta, mais simples, e até mais legível de fazer.

O `switch` aí é completamente desnecessário e colocar código desnecessário pode ser considerado errado por alguns. Eu costumo optar pelo que tem melhor performance sempre que a legibilidade não é afetada, neste caso a performance melhora a performance, então eu considero apenas mais correto não usá-lo.

Em outros situações poderia ser mais correto e até obrigatório o uso do `switch` ou outra forma de seleção entre opções.

Eu faria diferente já que as opções dos `case`s são invariantes e só o `default` é que varia em cada passo:

```js
console.log(`Repeating because one is less than ten !`);
console.log(`Repeating because two is less than ten !`);
console.log(`Repeating because three is less than ten !`);
for (var i = 4; i <= 10; i++) console.log(`Repeating because ${i} is less than ten !`);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/InvariantsInFor.js).

Comment: Dois negativos porque??? O código **refatorado** da AP é exatamente esse!!!

Comment: Eu sei quem, não preciso dizer que não foram por conta de erro ou algo assim. Cada um teve um motivo.

Comment: No caso, quando seria aconselhável utilizar um Switch ao invés de um IF, ELSE IF e ELSE, por exemplo ?

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger isso já foi respondido em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58192/101 e complementos para questões específicas e que vale só para algumas linguagens: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190736/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82667/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346695/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258024/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139313/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139313/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211841/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240410/101.

Answer (score 3):

Não tem nada de errado usar um  `switch` dentro de um `for`.

Pelo seu exemplo, quer fazer uma validação condicional, se não fosse um `switch`, precisaria por exemplo usar um `if`, e para esse caso o `switch` cai bem melhor.

Deve ser algum exercício e provavelmente quer mostrar a descrição do valor, mas veja que pode melhor um pouco... veja que parte da mensagem é sempre igual, então pode fazer o `switch` apenas para definir o texto do valor:

```js
for (var index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {
    var valor = `${index}`; 
    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            valor = "one";
            break;
        case 2:
            valor = "two";
            break;
        case 3:
            valor = "three";
            break;
    }
    
    console.log(`Repeating because ${valor} is less than ten !`)
}
```

Veja que não existe um "certo" ou "errado" absoluto, existem melhores ou piores maneiras de escrever o código, e boas práticas, e aqui outra sugestão pra te dar mais ideias de como resolver.

Comment: Ricado, é exatamente isso !
Esse é um exercício de um curso que estou fazendo onde quis "misturar" as coisas e pensei se seria correto fazer isso. 

Da forma que você respondeu o código acaba se adaptando caso no futuro eu mude  fixo de 10 para uma variável que o usuário venha a digitar, por exemplo. 

Obrigada !